# How to analyze CDF plot?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $z$ be a random variable, which is defined as $ Z = d^{\alpha}$. where $d$ is random variable. I tried to plot the CDF for $Z$ with different values of $\alpha$, which is:

[image]

So, average value(50th percentile) of $Z$ decreases with increase in $\alpha$ values. Is it correct?  Because if we increase the value of $\alpha$ the value of $Z$ also increases.

Comment: No, since $Z$ is between 0 and 1, increasing the exponent will decrease the value.